# More concise/idiomatic way of continuing with code if true is returned or exiting if false

Tags: c#

I have a few items -- let's just call them `itemA`, `itemB`, `itemC`, and `itemD` -- and I would like to validate each of them using a validation method I have written.

The validation method return type and signature is as follows:

```
public async Task<ValidationMessage> ValidateItem(MyClass item);
```

The `ValidationMessage` is a simple class:

```
public class ValidationMessage
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

To validate each item, currently I have the following code:

```
ValidationMessage result = new ValidationMessage();
result = await this.ValidateItem(itemA);
if (!result.Success)
{
    return result;
}
result = await this.ValidateItem(itemB);
if (!result.Success)
{
    return result;
}
result = await this.ValidateItem(itemC);
if (!result.Success)
{
    return result;
}
result = await this.ValidateItem(itemD);
return result;
```

As you can see, as soon as one of the items fails the validation method (meaning `result.Success == false`), I return and do not continue with validating the rest of them.

I think it's kind of tedious/ugly to have the repeated assignments to result and the repeated if statements. I was hoping there is some existing c# class/construct (perhaps LINQ can help) to write this more concisely. I made up the following to demonstrate what I'm sort of thinking:

```
ValidationMessage result = new ValidationMessage();
result = await this.ValidateItem(itemA).ContinueConditional(
            (r => r.Success) => await this.ValidateItem(itemB).ContinueConditional(
                (r => r.Success) => await this.ValidateItem(itemC).ContinueConditional(
                    (r => r.Success) => await this.ValidateItem(itemD))));
return result;
```

Basically, the return value of `this.ValidateItem(itemA)` is assigned to `result` and then this value goes into the `ContinueConditional`. If the result, `r`, has `Success == true`, then continue with validating `itemB`, and so on. If it's not successful, then exit out of that code and go straight to the return statement at the bottom, thus returning the item which failed the validation. If all items are validated then it will go to that return statement anyway.

I apologize for the long wall of text, especially if the c# construct already exists and is obvious. I appreciate any help with this.

**Note:** I have simplified my real example for the sake of posting this. One important part of the simplification is that `itemA`, `itemB`, `itemC`, and `itemD` *are not the same type*, despite referring to them as `MyClass` in the method signature above. So I can't just put them in a list and use LINQ. This also means I actually have different validation methods to accept the various items I have, but I didn't want to explain all that at the top in case it over-complicates things. The important part is that they all return `ValidationMessage`.

Comment: Could your items implement an interface, say `IValidatable`, then you could run them through a `foreach`.

Comment: I was thinking about doing this. I don't particularly like the idea of making them implement an interface just for the sake of validation, which all things considered is a small part of what they do.

Comment: Ok, didn't know the extent of what you were doing.  For fun I'm writing up an answer anyway :)

Comment: Go for it, I appreciate any ideas people come up with :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about inverting the logic around the check for success/failure?

```
ValidationMessage result = await this.ValidateItem(itemA);
if (result.Success) result = await this.ValidateItem(itemB);
if (result.Success) result = await this.ValidateItem(itemC);
if (result.Success) result = await this.ValidateItem(itemD);
return result;
```

Comment: I like this a lot. I guess I was so focused on returning as soon as I had the first fail that I didn't realize I could still return the first item that fails using this logic. Thank you!

Comment: I'm still curious though if there is such a construct following my logic.

Comment: Not that I know of. However let's see if someone has a better idea. For example the Interface approach is interesting albeit it requires some reworking of the existant classes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) to create a custom rule to loop through a list of models to validate.  This is more overhead than the other answers but it's a good approach with clean readable code.

First define your shared model

```
public class YourSharedModel()
{
    List<MyClass> Models = new List<MyClass>();
}
```

Define the validator:

```
public class SharedModelValidator : AbstractValidator<YourSharedModel>
{
    public SharedModelValidator()
    {
        CustomRule(BeValid)
    }

    public bool BeValid(ValidationErrors<YourSharedModel> validationFailures, YourSharedModel sharedModel, ValidationContext<YourSharedModel> validationContext)
    {
        for (var m in sharedModel.Models)
        {
            var result = YourValidationMethod(m);
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                validationFailures.AddFailureFor(x => m, result.ErrorMessage);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private YourValidationMethod(MyClass model)
    {
        // the code you have that actually validates
    }
}
```

Implementation would be something like:

```
var yourSharedModel = new YourSharedModel();
yourSharedModel.Models.Add(itemA);
yourSharedModel.Models.Add(itemB);
// etc

var validator = new SharedModelValidator();
var results = validator.Validate(yourSharedModel);
if (!results.IsValid)
{
    // do something with results.Errors
}
```

You could also keep all your errors and return false after the loop so that you get all the errors at once rather than one by one on submission, of course that's assuming a form post from a web application.  Makes for a better user friendly experience.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I like this a lot too. It is indeed validating a post request from a web application, so it would be handy to return all errors at once rather than return a 400 bad request with the first error, then return another 400 when the next request is made, etc.

Comment: Great!  This is definitely a big plus here then.  You can load up all those validation errors and return false out of the method and you can then print out the result errors all at once.  You could effectively put all your form data post back in the shared model and have the validator validate the whole form including the item models.  You can then write unit tests against it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? You can extend it to as many elements as you want.

```
var  validationRules = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>(){
                        () => ValidateItem(itemA),
                        () => ValidateItem(itemB),
                        () => ValidateItem(itemC),
                        () => ValidateItem(itemD),
            };

        ValidationMessage result = new ValidationMessage();


        foreach(var validationRule in validationRules)
        {
            result = await validationRule();

            if(!result)
                return result;
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Since the items aren't of the same type, maybe change the anonymous functions to the form `itemA.ValidateItem()`

Comment: But, I guess the OP didn't use that format, so never mind.

Comment: @MikeH it's a matter of choice. I think I wouldn't put validation logic inside the item. How items are mapped to the proper function depends on how these items are retrieved. Without a bigger context I can't tell how it can be done but surely there is always a way to map it very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interface and then add your items to a list that you `foreach` through:

```
ValidationMessage Test()
 {
  List<IValidatable> items = new List<IValidatable>();
  MyClass1 item1 = new MyClass1();
  MyClass2 item2 = new MyClass2();

  items.Add(item1);
  items.Add(item2);

  ValidationMessage result = null;
  foreach (var i in items)
  {
    result = i.ValidateItem();
    if (!result.Success) break;
  }

  return result;
}

interface IValidatable
{
  ValidationMessage ValidateItem();
}
public class ValidationMessage
{
  public bool Success { get; set; }
  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass1 : IValidatable
{
  public ValidationMessage ValidateItem()
  {
    return new ValidationMessage();
  }
}

public class MyClass2 : IValidatable
{
  public ValidationMessage ValidateItem()
  {
    return new ValidationMessage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (perhaps anorthodox) way to do it is to overload the && operator on ValidationMessage:

```
public class ValidationMessage
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public static ValidationMessage operator &(ValidationMessage message1, ValidationMessage message2)
    {
        return message1.Success ? message2 : message1;
    }

    public static ValidationMessage operator |(ValidationMessage message1, ValidationMessage message2)
    {
        return message1.Success ? message1 : message2;
    }

    public static bool operator true(ValidationMessage message)
    {
        return message.Success;
    }

    public static bool operator false(ValidationMessage message)
    {
        return !message.Success;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
return (await this.ValidateItem(ItemA)) &&
       (await this.ValidateItem(ItemB)) &&
       (await this.ValidateItem(ItemC)) &&
       (await this.ValidateItem(ItemD));
```